# python dictionary problems

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I'm having some difficulties in understanding somethings in dictionaoris.
If I have one big dictionary like this:

```
d = {'k1': ['v1', 'v2'], 'k2': ['v3'], 'k3': ['v4', 'v5', 'v6'], 'k4': ['v7', 'v8'], 'k5': ['v9', 'v10']}
```

Now, I would like to create a function:

```
def a_func(d)
```

And that function will check if at least one of the keys (k1/k2/k3...) is on of the value of another key and then check if the "another key" is one of the values of the "first key".
If yes, then print "OK".

Now, I thought about:

```
for key1 in d.items():
    for key2 in d[i+1]:
        if d[key1] == d[key2]:
            print "OK"
```

But it's not working good.
Any help please?

Comment: post the complete code please

Comment: Please show the expected sample dict and output. Otherwise it's hard to say what is your program supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `dict.items()` returns a list of tuples, where the first value in the tuple is the key, and the second is the value.

Try:

```
def a_func(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        for k2, v2 in d.items():
            if k in v2 and k2 in d[k]:
                return "OK"
```

Comment: the dictionariy isn't in the function, it's outside of it.

Comment: @user3003650 I'm not sure what you're saying but I edited my answer